# Trying to create column and set value in one begin/end statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add a new column to my table in SQL Server and populate it, but only it does not exist. I tried the following

```
if COL_LENGTH('MY_TABLE', 'NEW_COLUMN') is null
begin
  alter table MY_TABLE add NEW_COLUMN nvarchar(1) null;
  update MY_TABLE set NEW_COLUMN = N'N';
end;
```

But get the error:-
**Invalid column name 'NEW_COLUMN'**
In understand this is because the whole begin, end is evaluated at the same time. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the query is parsed before it is run. At that point, when it's parsed the column `NEW_COLUMN` does not exist and thus the `UPDATE` statement fails.

If `N'N'` is a default value, then add the column with a `DEFAULT` value and use `WITH VALUES` to have them pre-populated:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MY_TABLE (YOUR_COLUMN int);

INSERT INTO dbo.MY_TABLE (YOUR_COLUMN)
VALUES (1),
       (2);
GO

IF COL_LENGTH('MY_TABLE', 'NEW_COLUMN') IS NULL
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD NEW_COLUMN nchar(1) NULL DEFAULT N'N' WITH VALUES; --no need for an nvarchar for a length 1 string

END;

GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MY_TABLE;
```

Alternatively, if it shouldn't be the default value, you'll need to run the `UPDATE` in a different scope, so that it's parsed latter:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('MY_TABLE', 'NEW_COLUMN') IS NULL
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD NEW_COLUMN nchar(1) NULL; --no need for an nvarchar for a length 1 string
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE dbo.MY_TABLE SET NEW_COLUMN = N''N'';';

END;
```